# What is the correct term for a story that sits alongside another one in time and place?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, literary-techniques

What is the correct term for a book that sits alongside another book in time and universe, sharing some characters and events? Not after (a sequel) or before (a prequel), but parallel.

Example: I've just read "Ender's Shadow". It's a [something] of "Ender's Game".

Comment: Maybe there would be different terms depending on whether it is written by the same author or not ... "*Ender's Shadow* is a .... of *Ender's Game*"  but "*Wicked* is a .... of *The Wizard of Oz*"

Answer (score 15):

I would call them *[concurrent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concurrent)* stories:

> 1: operating or occurring at the same time
>    2: running parallel

Regarding filling your blank, I humbly offer:

> I've just read "Ender's Shadow". It's a **[*concurrent narrative*]** of "Ender's Game".
>   I've just read "Ender's Shadow". Its narrative ***is concurrent to*** "Ender's Game".

Comment: The only flaw with concurrent, I think, is that it makes no implication either way about the stories being *related*, merely happening chronologically at the same time.

Answer (score 11):

*[Ender's Shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Shadow)* is a **parallel** or **mirror** of *[Ender's Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game)*, just as *[Desperation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desperation_%28novel%29)* is a **parallel** or **mirror** of *[The Regulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Regulators)*.

Comment: I believe the term "parallel novel" is even included in some of Card's commentary regarding *Ender's Shadow* and *Ender's Game*.

Answer (score 9):

***Paraquel***.

*Paraquel* seems to already have a level of acceptance. I found a [few](http://thestorytellersscroll.blogspot.jp/2011/03/what-is-paraquel.html) different [links](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=paraquel) that [talk about it](http://jimhenry.conlang.org/review/paraquel.htm). A [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=paraquel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs) will reveal even more.

Funny how a word seems to be everywhere when one knows what to look for. My first thought was to use the prefix *~syn*, as in *synthesis* to form *synquel*. I Then looked online and discovered some [troll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_troll) has [trademarked the term](http://hles.org/synquel-huh). Which is lame. So I abandoned that idea and then considered one of the words suggested in a different answer,  *paralleloquel*.

While in my opinion it seemed to have more potential than other suggestions, the problem is that the word *parallel* means two things alongside that don't ever touch, which isn't appropriate for two stories that intertwine. However, if we strip down to just the prefix *~para*, we find that it means ["alongside, beyond, altered, contrary"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=para-), which is suitable enough. Especially the "alongside" and "altered" bits.

*~para* is Greek, and *~quel* is Latin, but I don't think anyone is too bothered about that kind of thing anymore.

So, my vote now is definitely for ***paraquel***.

> I've just read *Ender's Shadow*. It's a paraquel of *Ender's Game*.

Just for fun, also note in those links above some other interesting words such as *circumquel*, *interquel*, and *inquel*. One I don't see suggested, but could be, is *int**ra**quel*, which would be a story within a story.

Comment: Based on the edit I have converted my vote to +1. Your links are good. The word is organic and people are using it. I also think that other single-word suggestions congeal on the tongue. Furthermore, I like the more fundamental root of "para" vs. the more specific "parallel."   After all, one could debate the "parallelism" of two stories that are entirely unrelated but cross at a discrete point, and continue in different directions; this is not a problem for the root "para."

Comment: @Tolerance72: Sorry I got snarky. Glad we could get to a happier consensus. :)

Comment: Likewise, on all accounts. Best regards!

Answer (score 8):

I've referred to those exact books as being *coincident*.

Answer (score 6):

In another channel I've had **paralleloquel** as a suggestion. I quite like that.

Answer (score 3):

If they share some of the same characters AND events wouldn't they cross or touch at some point? i.e wouldn't be parallel.

Maybe tangential might describe that better.

Comment: I see them as parallel and partially overlapping, as opposed to occasionally intersecting.

Comment: @Roy how is partially overlapping different to occasionally intersecting?

Comment: I like "tangential" and I've seen it used. Sometimes it means something more akin to "branching" but often it means exactly what we have here.

Comment: @Matt: I failed to think of a way to describe the concept concisely with words, so if a plotline had a graphical representation, https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-T1ZJv21Iu0s/UAaB3Sj5m2I/AAAAAAAAAXY/SvXcedbNIEs/s640/plotlines.png

Comment: @Roy Oh! Very good, then. :)

Comment: That's a nice diagram @Roy. I like all these geometric metaphors too.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes [isochronous](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sa=X&ei=xGEGUMjbCYvorQeYy7ihBg&ved=0CEAQvwUoAQ&q=define%20isochronous&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e3b682a5d17fe3db&biw=1024&bih=653) is used that way

Answer (score 3):

I would say that "Ender's Shadow is [contemporary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contemporary?s=t&ld=1086) with Ender's Game."

Comment: Also: `contemporaneous`, depending on how one wants to phrase the statement.

Comment: Contemporary, with respect to works, might imply they were written at similar times, and in this case, they are not.

Comment: @McKay Technically correct.  Which, of course, is the best type of correct to be.  The word is still a good one, however, and to disambiguate, one might instead say that "The plot of Ender's Shadow is contemporary with that of Ender's Game."

Comment: @KazDragon Yeah, it might help to be more specific when using this word in this fashion, but it can work.

Answer (score 2):

Contemporaneous, contemporary.

Example: I've just read "Ender's Shadow". It's **contemporaneous to** "Ender's Game".

Answer (score 1):

If we're considering *synquel* (mentioned by Dave M G), then another option is **conquel**.  The only "official" reference for this that I know of is the ever-so-reputable [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=conquel), but that may be good enough for this purpose.

If we're coining our own and throwing scraps of Latin together, we might try *coquel* (basically same as *conquel*) or *juxtaquel*.

Comment: Changed my suggestion from *synquel* to *paraquel*. Putting aside trademark problems, *paraquel* seems to already be more established.

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneous
adjective
1. existing, occurring, or operating at the same time; concurrent

Answer (score 0):

"same setting" is a (probably colloquial) term that I've seen used to represent stories that occur concurrently and (mostly) separately.

> I've just read "Ender's Shadow". It has the *same setting* as "Ender's Game".